# Import in protobuf files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a plugin in my app as `library root`. The plugin uses `protobuf`. So I have some `*.proto` instructions. In these `proto` files, I use import for other local `proto` files. When I try to generate all works correctly, but in IntelliJ, I see errors (words marked by red color) in an import part and a name part. How can I resolve it for correct displaying in IntelliJ?

[image]

where: "protobuf/plugin_primitives.proto"
file with

```
// Point.
message  PointDto {
  double x = 1;
  double y = 2;
}
```

my generator

```
# create an array with all *.proto inside ./protobuf
filesList=(protobuf/*.proto)

# iterate through array using a counter
for ((i=1; i<=${#filesList[@]}; i++)); do

  # create file name
  fileName=${filesList[$i]}

  # check file name for not empty and has .proto ending
  if [[ $fileName == *".proto" ]]; then

    # echo information on step
    echo "generate:" "$fileName"

    # generate
    protoc --dart_out=./lib/src --plugin=protoc-gen-dart="$PUB_CACHE"/bin/protoc-gen-dart --java_out=./android/src/main/kotlin --kotlin_out=./android/src/main/kotlin --swift_out=./ios/Classes ./"$fileName"

  fi

done
```

works correctly, I see error only in `*.proto` in IntelliJ, but it confuses developers about correct class names. How can I resolve it for correct displaying in IntelliJ?

UPD:
I found, if I add in `Preferences`->`Languages & Frameworks`->`Protocol Buffers` strong location to my `*.proto` it will be green. But I have many places for `*.proto`, for example for each plugin in my app, and some `*.proto` can have an equal name, like `featuresDto` for each plugin. How can I add library-dependent location instead of strong?

Comment: Wouldnt that very much depend on how exactly your overall project setup is defined within IntelliJ?

Comment: What settings should I pay attention to? can you please be more detailed?

Comment: I mean: how did you define your project in IntelliJ? IntelliJ isnt just some editor, you typically *define* a project with specific properties.